# Django admin: adding pagination links in list of objects to top

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to have the pagination links that appear at the bottom of a list of objects in Django's admin interface at the top as well?

Can this be done without changing the admin templates? I suspect not, given the lack of a [`ModelAdmin` option](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options), but thought I'd see if anyone had done this before I dug into the template code.

I really, really don't want to have to copy and paste [`change_list.html`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html) into a new file, just so I can add a pagination line - that'll make changing Django versions painful, since I'll have to check if anything's changed in that file, and re-apply my change.

Comment: Why is changing the template out of the question?

Comment: @John Mee - thanks for taking a look - see my edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not copy `change_list.html`, instead create a new template that  **extends it**:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}

{% block result_list %}
      {% block pagination %} {{ block.super }} {% endblock %} <!-- pagination -->
      {{ block.super }}  <!-- rest of results list -->
{% endblock %}
```

Then pass the new template's name to `ModelAdmin` in `change_list_template` attribute - [doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_list_template).

Comment: Any way to put it on top only? without bottom –

Answer (score 1):

The source code implementing the django admin template for `change_list.html` has a `content` block so if you create a file `change_list.html` under 'admin' folder in your templates directory and add this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{# added pagination to top as well as bottom #}
{% block content %}{% pagination cl %}{{ block.super }}{% endblock %}
```

it should do the trick!

Comment: Any way to put it on top only? without bottom

Comment: you'd need to go in the source code and look if the admin page has a bottom block template tag. if it does you override it to be without the bottom

Comment: I had to include `{% load admin_list %}` in the template.